# Using python to return a list of squared integers

Tags: python, list

I'm looking to write a function that takes the integers within a list, such as [1, 2, 3], and returns a new list with the squared integers; [1, 4, 9]

How would I go about this?

PS - just before I was about to hit submit I noticed Chapter 14 of O'Reilly's 'Learning Python' seems to provide the explanation I'm looking for (Pg. 358, 4th Edition)

But I'm still curious to see what other solutions are possible

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can (and should) use [**list comprehension**](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
squared = [x**2 for x in lst]
```

`map` makes one function call per element and while `lambda` expressions are quite handy, using `map` + `lambda` is mostly slower than list comprehension.

[*Python Patterns - An Optimization Anecdote*](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str.html) is worth a read.

Answer (score 8):

Besides lambda and list comprehensions, you can also use generators. List comprehension calculates all the squares when it's called, generators calculate each square as you iterate through the list. Generators are better when input size is large or when you're only using some initial part of the results.

```
def generate_squares(a):
    for x in a:
        yield x**2 

# this is equivalent to above
b = (x**2 for x in a)
```

Comment: Important to mention imo (because it can be confusing at the beginning), you can iterate one generator only *once*.

Comment: For completeness: you can force eager evaluation of the generator (i.e. obtain the actual results) trivially with e.g. `tuple(generate_squares(original))` or `list(generate_squares(original))`.

Answer (score 6):

```
squared = lambda li: map(lambda x: x*x, li)
```

Comment: More "pythonic" would be: `lambda lst: [x*x for x in lst]`

Comment: @phihag Why introducing a lambda while `[x*x for x li]` fits well ?

Comment: @eyquem Probably because the question was "I'm looking to write a **function** that..."

Comment: @phihag Well, what's going wrong with `def squarification(li):  return [x*x for x in li]` ?

Comment: @eyquem some people have strangely strict notions of what qualifies as functional programming - the same way that many people have strange (though usually not so much because of being strict) notions of what qualifies as OOP. :)

Comment: @eyquem Nothing, it's completely fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should know about `map` built-in which takes a function as the first argument and an iterable as the second and returns a list consisting of items acted upon by the function.
For e.g.

```
>>> def sqr(x):
...     return x*x
... 
>>> map(sqr,range(1,10))
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
>>>
```

There is a better way of writing the sqr function above, namely using the nameless `lambda` having quirky syntax. (Beginners get confused looking for return stmt)

```
>>> map(lambda x: x*x,range(1,10))
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Apart from that you can use list comprehension too.

```
result = [x*x for x in range(1,10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [x ** 2 for x in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

good remark of kefeizhou, but then there is no need of a generator function, a generator expression is right:

```
for sq in (x*x for x in li):
   # do
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lambda` with `map` to get this.

```
lst=(3,8,6)
sqrs=map(lambda x:x**2,lst)
print sqrs
```