# How to square and add numbers in a generated list in python?

Tags: python, list

For an assignment, I have to square or cube each number in a generated list and add them together. So far, I've used the list function to create a list between two values that the user inputs and attempted to square each number, but I have yet to add them together. I'm not sure what exactly to do from here, as I'm getting some sort of generator error.

```
squares = "squares"
cubes = "cubes"
exit = "exit"

command = input("Please enter a command ('squares,' 'cubes,' or 'exit' to terminate): ")


while True:
    if command == squares:
        integer = int(input("Please enter an initial integer: "))
        term = int(input("Please enter the number of terms to be generated: "))

        for x in range(integer, integer+term+1):
            sqnums = (x**2 for x in range)
            print(sqnums)
        command = input("Please enter a command ('squares,' 'cubes,' or 'exit' to terminate): ")

    if command == cubes:
        integer = int(input("Please enter an initial integer: "))
        term = int(input("Please enter the number of terms to be generated: "))

        command = input("Please enter a command ('squares,' 'cubes,' or 'exit' to terminate): ")

    if command == exit:
        print("Goodbye")
        break
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using python to return a list of squared integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079094/using-python-to-return-a-list-of-squared-integers)

Comment: The code you posted is confusing, but don't you just need `sum(x**2 for x in xrange(integer, integer+term+1)`?

Comment: i tried that and it wasn't working for me until i realized that it was a simple parentheses error i made that was messing it up. thanks for the help!